# Apple Watch app installation issue - NSExtensionPointIdentifier

Tags: ios, watchkit, xcode-6.2

I'm trying to install an app with WatchKit App and WatchKit Extension onto an iOS8.1 phone, from Xcode 6.2.

I have the Deployment Target set at 8.1
and the Base SDK at 8.2.

I get this error:

```
This app contains an app extension that specifies an extension
point identifier that is not supported on this version of iOS
for the value of the NSExtensionPointIdentifier key in its Info.plist
```

I've seen some similar questions but not found a solution that works. Is there a way to programmatically handle the lower iOS version?

Comment: What is the value in the Info.plist and why can`t you just set the higher OS Value?

Comment: @LoVo the value is "com.apple.watchkit" for NSExtensionPointIdentifier in the Extension plist so can't see how I could change that

Comment: You only can use the apple watch extension when you set the minimum target to 8.2 maybe you even have to add the key-value pair: "MinimumOSVersion" = "8.2" to the apple watch extension Info.plist yourself if it is not there already

Comment: Tried the MinimumOSVersion already, didn't work.

Comment: @LoVo But you were correct about the minimum target - I've fixed the issue now by changing the extension's Deployment Target to 8.2 (while the main app's deployment target is still 8.1). thanks!

Comment: @LoVo where do I go to do that?

Comment: @zumzum there should be a Info.plist file in your Watch extension, if there is no key - pair for `MinimumOSVersion` you add it yourself.

Comment: I added MinimumOSVersion 8.2 to the extension plist but it's still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer this (using @LoVo's comment) - I fixed the issue by changing the deployment target to 8.2 in the Extension's Build Settings (not in the main app's build settings).

The main app's deployment target can be set at a lower deployment target, mine is now 7.0.